# How to increment the time stamp in Jmeter using the random function

Tags: jmeter

I am using the following function to get the time stamp and this is giving me the current time stamp but I want to increment to tomorrow or by `n` day or `r` week or `l` month.

```
${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SS'Z')}
```

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [__timeShift() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) which allows adding or subtracting arbitrary amount of  days, hours, minutes and seconds to/from the current/provided date

Example syntax:

[image]

Text version just in case:

```
- Tomorrow:     `${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SS'Z',,P1D,,)}`
- Week after:   `${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SS'Z',,P7D,,)}`
- etc.
```

More information:

- [Duration.parse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-)
- [Creating Dates in JMeter Using the TimeShift Function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-dates-in-jmeter-using-the-timeshift-function)